Ubuntu 24 cannot mirror my laptop screen with my TV monitor
I have Ubuntu 24 freshly installed. I have the system up to date and Nvidia drivers installed. My Laptop is Dell G15 and my TV monitor is SAMSUNG 32 SMART FULL HD - UA32T5300AU. My Laptop native resolution is 1920 x 1080 and the native resolution of my TV is 1366 x 768
My laptop is plugged in to my TV via HDMI cable and when I go to Display Setting -> Display in Ubuntu 24 and select multiple display then Mirror, I only find 4 revolutions see image below and 1366 X 768 (my TV native resolution ) is not part of them. If I choose 1920 x 1080, the same as my laptop native resolution, the screen looks ugly.
Resolutions available:

The result of the command is below:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    120.21*+ 120.21    60.21  
   1680x1050    120.21  
   1400x1050    120.21  
   1600x900     120.21  
   1280x1024    120.21  
   1400x900     120.21  
   1280x960     120.21  
   1368x768     120.21  
   1280x800     120.21  
   1152x864     120.21  
   1280x720     120.21  
   1024x768     120.21  
   1024x768i    120.21  
   960x720      120.21  
   928x696      120.21  
   896x672      120.21  
   1024x576     120.21  
   960x600      120.21  
   832x624      120.21  
   960x540      120.21  
   800x600      120.21  
   840x525      120.21  
   864x486      120.21  
   700x525      120.21  
   800x450      120.21  
   640x512      120.21  
   700x450      120.21  
   640x480      120.21  
   720x405      120.21  
   720x400      120.21  
   684x384      120.21  
   640x400      120.21  
   576x432      120.21  
   640x360      120.21  
   640x350      120.21  
   512x384      120.21  
   512x384i     120.21  
   512x288      120.21  
   416x312      120.21  
   480x270      120.21  
   400x300      120.21  
   432x243      120.21  
   320x240      120.21  
   360x202      120.21  
   360x200      120.21  
   320x200      120.21  
   320x180      120.21  
   320x175      120.21  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
   1366x768      59.79 +
   1920x1080     59.94*   50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94

Thanks.

You could try manually setting the resolution as it's already listed in your xrandr output, try: xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1366x768

I tried it but the mirror option still does not have 1366x768 as option.

Just to clarify my issue, I can use my TV monitor as main screen with 1366x768 if I select Join instead of Mirror, however, in Join mode with 1366x768 as resolution, when I open a window, it shows on my laptop and I have to move it to my TV screen which is very annoying.
